what is the estimated attorney fee after the non-provisional application is filed?
After a non-provisional patent application is filed:

Is responding to office actions the only work left to be done?
If so, what is the expected attorney fee for these remaining work?


I can't answer since all my patents were processed by corporate attorneys, but the amount of work to respond to office actions can vary dramatically between patents.

The primary work is responding to Office Actions. That can involve in-person interviews with the examiner and has a wide range of difficulties depending on what documents are cited.
Besides OAs there are other things like consideration of filing continuation applications.
It’s hard to give an average but it might be $1000 - $5000.
